# RemoteApp steals focus from other applications

Tags: window, windows-server-2012-r2, focus, terminal-services, remoteapp

I have an issue with RemoteApp opened applications through Terminal Services, they randomly steal the focus from other apps.

When you have a RemoteApp application opened in the background and you are working in a different app sometimes the remote app takes the focus and its window gets over the other app, it happens randomly and in different computers with different SO versions, Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 so I think this is a server problem (Windows Server 2012 R2).

I made a network scan and there aren't micro disconnections

Does anybody know why can this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: We have also seen this issue. My suspicion in our environment is this seems to happen when the network is really slow ! (i.e.,) if the RemoteApp is accessed via a slow VPN connection.

Comment: I somewhere read this could be caused by micro disconnections in the local network causing the lose of packages, I did a network scan and I couldn't see any problem with the network or package drops, so I discarded this option.

Comment: I just did a network speed analysis between host and server and we have 12Mb/s, we are no more than 6 person using it simultaneously (up  to 2 RemoteApp) and the average Kb per app is 100Kb/s, so i don't think this is the problem